# Error running loki invalid database .error creating index client

Tags: grafana

I am trying to run loki stack. Running the helm command through the `grafana-loki.yaml` file -

```
loki:
  enabled: true
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    storageClassName: azurefile-csi-loki
    size: 1Gi

promtail:
  enabled: true

# fluent-bit:
#   enabled: false

grafana:
  enabled: true
  sidecar:
    datasources:
      enabled: true
  image:
    tag: 7.5.0
# prometheus:
#   enabled: false
```

Created the storage class name by -

```
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: azurefile-csi-loki
provisioner: file.csi.azure.com
allowVolumeExpansion: true
parameters:
  csi.storage.k8s.io/provisioner-secret-name: azure-secret
  csi.storage.k8s.io/provisioner-secret-namespace: management
  csi.storage.k8s.io/node-stage-secret-name: azure-secret
  csi.storage.k8s.io/node-stage-secret-namespace: management
  csi.storage.k8s.io/controller-expand-secret-name: azure-secret
  csi.storage.k8s.io/controller-expand-secret-namespace: management
  resourceGroup: iot # optional, only set this when storage account is not in the same resource group as agent node
  storageAccount: aksrediscache
  shareName: loki-storage
reclaimPolicy: Retain
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=0
  - gid=0
  - mfsymlinks
  - cache=strict # https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs
  - nosharesock # reduce probability of reconnect race
  - actimeo=30 # reduce latency for metadata-heavy workload
```

I get the error below when I run the helm command -

```
helm upgrade -i loki-stack grafana/loki-stack -f grafana-loki.yaml -n management


level=info ts=2021-08-28T14:52:20.459348779Z caller=main.go:130 msg="Starting Loki" version="(version=2.2.0, branch=HEAD, revision=a27c79913)"
level=info ts=2021-08-28T14:52:20.459628282Z caller=server.go:229 http=[::]:3100 grpc=[::]:9095 msg="server listening on addresses"
level=info ts=2021-08-28T14:52:20.459704683Z caller=modules.go:477 msg="RulerStorage is not configured in single binary mode and will not be started."
level=info ts=2021-08-28T14:52:20.527680699Z caller=table_manager.go:241 msg="loading table index_18867"
level=error ts=2021-08-28T14:52:20.667955983Z caller=log.go:106 msg="error running loki" err="invalid database\nerror creating index client\ngithub.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/chunk/storage.NewStore\n\t/src/loki/vendor/github.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/chunk/storage/factory.go:179\ngithub.com/grafana/loki/pkg/loki.(*Loki).initStore\n\t/src/loki/pkg/loki/modules.go:319\ngithub.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules.(*Manager).initModule\n\t/src/loki/vendor/github.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules/modules.go:103\ngithub.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules.(*Manager).InitModuleServices\n\t/src/loki/vendor/github.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules/modules.go:75\ngithub.com/grafana/loki/pkg/loki.(*Loki).Run\n\t/src/loki/pkg/loki/loki.go:220\nmain.main\n\t/src/loki/cmd/loki/main.go:132\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:204\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374\nerror initialising module: store\ngithub.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules.(*Manager).initModule\n\t/src/loki/vendor/github.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules/modules.go:105\ngithub.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules.(*Manager).InitModuleServices\n\t/src/loki/vendor/github.com/cortexproject/cortex/pkg/util/modules/modules.go:75\ngithub.com/grafana/loki/pkg/loki.(*Loki).Run\n\t/src/loki/pkg/loki/loki.go:220\nmain.main\n\t/src/loki/cmd/loki/main.go:132\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:204\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374"
```

I am not sure why it is giving error inspite all mounting of PVC is successful -

```
NAME                     STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS         AGE
storage-grafana-loki-0   Bound    pvc-2e3023d3-2922-444d-a127-4f131c069bd2   1Gi        RWO            azurefile-csi-loki   41m
storage-loki-stack-0     Bound    pvc-8ece834f-fd24-43ad-9121-40794b72fd1c   1Gi        RWO            azurefile-csi-loki   31m
```

Can someome help me on this ?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? What was the solution accordingly?